# What are those sets of pages called which a user can see when not logged in?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm creating a website and I need to keep the code organized by correctly labeling some parts of the code.

For this, I'm looking for a way to put "the set of pages which a user can see when not logged in" in a very succinct way. The less words the better, but keeping the clarity is also necessary. Ideally it would be a 1-2 words label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

> **Public** web pages. (pages anyone can view).

Comment: public pages is enough because of the overall context - but of course I don't expect you to know the context. Thanks again.